# What traditional Linux facilities/configurations have been incorporated by systemd?

Tags: systemd

As I work more with latest distro versions (Debian Jessie or CentOS 7), everyday I find 1 thing that was previously configured in some way, and now is managed by systemd. i.e. swap partition mount no longer controller by fstab, laptop lid close action no longer an /etc/acpi configuration etc.

We know the obvious (init, logging, network...), but could someone make or point to a comprehensive list of things that are now managed via systemd and before were managed differently?

Comment: _facilotated_ isn't a word, but neither was the original _fagocitated_.  That latter, however, is a common mis-spelling (by people who haven't seen it written down I suspect) of _phagocytized_, which seems slightly inappropriate.  Have an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia has a very detailed entry about systemd, including a list of components.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Ancillary_components)

Unfortunately it does not list what was replaced before.